# How do you find names or ids of buttons in gmail?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program in python with which I open gmail, log in, and send an email from my account. The only problem is I can't find the name or id of any of the buttons I need to have either a name or id for. Can anyone help me with this? I'm sorry if this question is considered too simplistic but I have been looking all through the code I can see and I can't seem to find it. I can seem to do everything I need to do for this program *except this*. Thank you.

Edit: I have been using Selenium. Basically how the program will work is it opens my browser, goes to gmail, inputs my email in the appropriate box, clicks the button to move on, inputs my password in the appropriate box, and clicks the button to sign in. Then it clicks the "compose email" button and inputs text then clicks the "send" button. I've already basically made it work *apart from the buttons* which is the issue.

Edit:

```
def openGmail():
    from selenium import webdriver
    import time
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/elliot/Desktop/chromedriver')
    driver.get('http://www.gmail.com');
    signinbox = driver.find_element_by_name('identifier')
    signinbox.send_keys('myemail@gmail.com')
    signinbutton = driver.find_element_by_id('identifierNext')
    signinbutton.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    passwordbox = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
    passwordbox.send_keys('mypassword')
    passwordbutton = driver.find_element_by_id('passwordNext')
    passwordbutton.click()
```

Comment: Show us what you have been trying.

Comment: For stuff like that, you can either use the google mail api, or if you really want to have a "browser" simulation you could use `selenium`

Comment: @ElisByberi I've edited my question with what the program will do.

Comment: @user1767754 I have been using Selenium. I've edited the question.

Comment: @Elliot You did write all these words! Why you did not write code itself. It would be much shorter.

Comment: @ElisByberi regardless, this is how the program works. I managed to find the id for the "move on" button, guessed the id for the "sign in" button cause I completely forgot where I found the id for the "move on" button, and i've been looking all through the code for the "compose email" button but I can't find it and I can't guess it.

Comment: @Elliot I didn't read it at all! That's why I keep asking for code.

Comment: @ElisByberi I don't see why you wouldn't just read it but I'll upload the code in one moment

Comment: @Elliot I can not keep track of what is going on with just words. I need code. My brain works like an interpreter.

Comment: @ElisByberi I just uploaded the code. "myemail@gmail.com" stands in place of my email and "mypassword" stands in place of my actual password.

Comment: @Elliot Some other peer may help you. It took me all 12 minutes to get code.

Answer (score 0):

in google or secure website similar to that, they don't use buttons basically
so what you can do is use css selectors in selenium

example

```
WebElement nxtBtn = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("*[text='Next']"));
```

or

```
WebElement nxtBtn = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("*[innertext='Next']"));
```